# Whitespace tokenizer for training BERT language model from scratch with Huggingface

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to train a BERT language model from scratch using [Huggingface API](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train). For that I need to build a tokenizer that tokenize the text data based on white spaces only, nothing else. I understand that there are multiple tonkenizers available in Huggingface (such as `BPE`, `WordPiece`) that produce good results for language models but for my use case I want to tokenize text input based on whitespace only and generate vocabs that should not have any kind of special characters viz "##" in front of words.

For example: the input `Hello, y'all! How are you?` should be tonkenized as:

`Hello,`, `y'all!`, `How`, `are`, `you?`

I checked the documentation [[1]](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) and [[2]](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) but did not find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why not just `'Hello, y'all! How are you?'.split()`?

Comment: I understand but where would this `.split` will go in the pipeline?

Comment: With pipeline you mean a [huggingface pipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html)? Please post the code of your pipeline. You probably need a wrapper class with at least a tokenize method.

Comment: The code is already available here: https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train

Comment: The easiest solution to this is that you just create a class, add it to the pipeline and read the error messages to see what methods the pipeline expects.